# Uninstall Share Lib In Linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I have tried to install MYSQL 5.6.29 on Linux Centos and installed file "MySQL-shared-5.6.29-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64" but i found its wrong file which i have installed. Now when i am trying to install correct file "MySQL-shared-5.6.29-1.el6.x86_6" then getting below error.

`/usr/share/doc/MySQL-shared-5.6.29/README from install of MySQL-shared-5.6.29-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-shared-5.6.29-
1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64`

My installation was incomplete and only able to install 3 rpm packages. I run "yum remove mysql" but its un-install only one package please guide me to find & un-install MYSQL related packages.

Answer (score 0):

issue fixed through these commands:

`rpm -qa|grep -i SQL -- find installed rpm packages
rpm -e -- find installed package and then place the package name
rpm -i package_name.rpm -- to install packages 
yum remove mysql-libs`